# Can we insert multiple row in one query in Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi below in a given scenario

```
 some_model_id = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 some_model_id.each do |some_id|
   SomeOtherModel.create(some_column: some_id)
 end
```

Here `insert` query will run `n` times depending on `some_model_id` size

**Is there a way where I can do it in single query on some other better approach then this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem, it allows to insert in the bulk.

Answer (score 5):

ActiveRecord create can also take array of insert statement which will formulate only single ActiveRecord object but it still execute multiple insert statement in database. Refer following code

```
SomeOtherModel.create([{some_column: some_id}, {some_column: some_id}, {some_column:some_id}])
```

To insert multiple record at once it is better to use raw SQL insert command with multiple values.

Comment: This solution, while it does work, fires a single `INSERT` query for each record you are inserting. The benefit is that you get all your `*_save` and/or `*_create` modal callbacks for each record (whereas doing a raw SQL `INSERT` for your `n` rows bypasses your model logic). The cost, however, is that your query turns into `n` queries and the overall action is much slower. Probably a good reason to practice pushing business logic into the DB when and where possible!

Answer (score 4):

### insert_all (Rails 6+)

Starting from `Rails 6`, `ActiveRecord` supports inserting multiple rows using one SQL query out of the box.

Please, have a look at [insert_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/insert_all)